# Guardar el valor de una variable entre diferentes ejecuciones en Java

Tags: java, base-de-datos, variables, sesiones, sqllite

No se si habré formulado la pregunta del todo bien, pero lo que necesito es:
Tengo una Base de Datos en SQLite que creo dentro de la propia ejecución del programa, por medio de un método detecto si la base de datos ya existe y, en ese caso, no la vuelvo a crear.
Sin embargo, me gustaría tener una variable (un boolean) que fuera algo como bd_creada y que fuera true si ya existiese la bd o false en caso contrario, en mi código tengo una variable que debería actuar tal que así "hayDatos" pero no lo hace del todo, cuando inicializo el código la variable se inicializa en false.
Mi pregunta es, existe alguna manera de inicializar una variable según el estado de la úlima ejecución del programa?(sin guardarla en una BD).

```
public class DBManager {

private static Connection con;
private static boolean hayDatos = false;
```

...

```
private void inicializar() throws SQLException {
    if (!hayDatos) {
        hayDatos = true;

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='PROFESORES'");

        if (!res.next()) {


            
            (PROCESO DE CREACIÓN DE LA BD)
```

Comment: Si no la guardas, el código no tiene manera de saber lo que valía en la anterior ejecución. Si no quieres usar la BD, puedes usar un archivo de configuración... pero el resultado es el mismo, debes utilizar algún sistema externo para almacenar el valor. Lo más básico sería crear un archivo .txt con un 1 o un 0 dentro, lo abres, lo lees y si hay un 1, existe la DB. No necesitas librerías y tan solo unas pocas líneas de código. Mejor opción sería al menos ponerle nombre, `db_created=1`, por ejemplo. Así en el futuro puedes añadir más opciones si te hacen falta... pero yo usaría la DB sin más :)

Comment: Perfecto, eso me iría de perlas, no puedo usar la DB porque en el caso de que NO esté creada. Como haría para saber si el valor es 1 o 0?

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo sería verificando si el archivo que contiene la base de datos existe. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7100597/5587982) y sus respuestas para más detalles.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me fue perfecta esta solución, mil gracias ^^.